# Can I use a parameter in C# to send data back to the caller?

Tags: c#

I usually send data back to the calling code using return. However this time I have to send two kinds of data:

```
public IEnumerable<AccountDetail> ShowDetails(string runTime)
```

Is it possible for me to send the value of runTime back to the calling code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes

```
public IEnumerable<AccountDetail> ShowDetails(ref string runTime)
```

The calling code would also have the ref keyword:

```
.ShowDetails(ref runTime);
```

Comment: If I was to use the out keyword what would be the syntax? I wonder if that would be more appropriate as this is and always will be a one-way reference. I would never set the value of runTime and send it to the method used to create a report.

Comment: Just replace ref with out in both cases (method declaration and caller).

Comment: Yes. It's worth noting the difference in the two. With `ref` as competent_tech has it now `runTime` **must** have a value before assigned before the call, and the method may choose to leave it alone. With `out` the value may or may not have a value before assigning but the method **must** assign a value to it, unless it throws an exception, even if it e.g. returns false to mean it failed to do anything useful to the `out` parameter.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it's possible via either the [`ref`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) or [`out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx) keywords.

Usually, though, the need to do this points to a design failure elsewhere... not always, there are some good cases for this, but often enough that I'd want to spend a bit of time thinking about what I'm really doing first.

Comment: I'd agree about design failure but in this instance I have the two things. The output of a report and the run time. Do you think this might qualify as okay?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing a lot more about the project... and probably not worth the time to find out for one instance. But if you find yourself doing this more often, it's likely time to refactor.

Comment: As Joel points out, often it's a code smell; for instance, you could create a class with multiple properties and return that. There's also the Tuple class in .NET 4; however, that can lead to unclear code.

Answer (score 3):

There are three options.

1. ref keyword
2. out variable
3. Global variable.

Comment: Callback function, property of the class being called, return a `dynamic` object that has the report and the run time as members ... there are many more than just three options.

Comment: Hello and thanks. If I was to use the out keyword what would be the syntax? I wonder if that would be more appropriate as this is and always will be a one-way reference. I would never set the value of runTime and send it to the method used to create a report.